# Ennui Content Slider Display two images at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am trying to use the Ennui Content slider to display two images per sequence of images.

http://ennuidesign.com/demo/contentslider/ this is the slider

I am not sure what I need to change or do to get it to do this

Any ideas

*cheers

Comment: Posting a jsfiddle of your code might help getting specific answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to slice your HTML in the way that inside (ex) one container you will get (new) two child elements (2 images or whatever.).